# Stop when the last element is reached in an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
 var elem = $('#progress-text');
 count = 0;
 wordsArray = ["1", "2", "3", "Bye"];
 setInterval(function () {
  count++;
  elem.fadeOut(400, function () {
   $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
   });
 }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#progress-text{
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress-text">
</div>

<button id="show">
Show
</button>
```

Please review the above code.

**Problem 1:** The elements in the array are `1, 2, 3, Bye` but when the `Show` button is clicked, the first element in the array is not shown, it starts with "2" after 2 seconds.

**2:** I need to stop looping after the last element in the array is reached.
That means `1, 2, 3, Bye` will only be shown once.

Comment: You could try counting the array keys, saving that as a variable and then decrementing the value and killing it when it gets to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment counter in the `fadout()` callback and use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to cancels a timed action

```
  elem.text(wordsArray[count++]); //To immediately show the text
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    elem.fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      count++;
      if (count == wordsArray.length) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
```

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
  var elem = $('#progress-text');
  var count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["1", "2", "3", "Bye"];
  elem.text(wordsArray[count++]);
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    elem.fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      count++;
      if (count == wordsArray.length) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#progress-text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress-text">
</div>

<button id="show">
Show
</button>
```

Comment: Awesome.. But on button click, the first element also shows up after 2 seconds, is there any way to show it immediately and then show rest of the elements in the 2 seconds interval?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
 var elem = $('#progress-text');
 count = 0;
 wordsArray = ["1", "2", "3", "Bye"];
    elem.text(wordsArray[count++]);
 var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  elem.fadeOut(400, function () {
   $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
  count++;
                if (count === wordsArray.length) { 
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
   });
 }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
#progress-text{
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress-text">
</div>

<button id="show">
Show
</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't solves anything. Please check your code.

Comment: I updated a little bit to make the number "1" appear right away when the button is clicked. It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
 var elem = $('#progress-text');
 count = 0;
 wordsArray = ["1", "2", "3", "Bye"];
 var myVar =setInterval(function (){

  if(wordsArray.length>count){
   elem.fadeOut(400, function () {
   $(this).text(wordsArray[count-1]).fadeIn(400);});
    count++;
   }
   else
    clearInterval(myVar);

 }, 2000);

 });
```

```css
#progress-text{
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress-text">
</div>

<button id="show">
Show
</button>
```